# Training LUIS to recognise a job ticket number

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to train LUIS to recognise a request for a status update on a job ticket (analogous to a JIRA/GitHub issue ID).  The job ticket number will be of the format [Letter S or s][One or more digits].  E.g.:

"What is that status on S344?"

Intent: StatusUpdate

Entity: Ticket = S344

After labelling a number of utterances LUIS can recognise the intent with high confidence, but is never able to identify the Ticket entity, even when I use the exact ticket number I've labelled as the entity in a labelled utterance.

I've also tried adding a Regex feature `[sS]{1}\d+`, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is there something special I need to do to make this work, or do I just need to persevere adding more training utterances?

Comment: Are you training your model after adding the utterances? And then, are you republishing your updated model?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: That sounds strange then... is the BOT not recognizing the entity or in LUIS site if you send a new utterance it doesn't recognize the ticket either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this myself and after 7 utterances, LUIS is recognizing the ticket just fine. What I did was:

1. Send a couple of utterances
2. Train
3. Send a new bunch of utterances (different tickets number and phrases)
4. Train again

I exported my LUIS App for you (below and [here](http://pastebin.com/Z7TwJ1gv))

```
{
  "luis_schema_version": "1.3.0",
  "name": "testticket",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "None"
    },
    {
      "name": "StatusUpdate"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "Ticket"
    }
  ],
  "composites": [],
  "bing_entities": [],
  "actions": [],
  "model_features": [],
  "regex_features": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "what is that status on s344?",
      "intent": "StatusUpdate",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Ticket",
          "startPos": 5,
          "endPos": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "status of s124",
      "intent": "StatusUpdate",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Ticket",
          "startPos": 2,
          "endPos": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "what's the status of s4",
      "intent": "StatusUpdate",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "please tell me the status of s4",
      "intent": "StatusUpdate",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Ticket",
          "startPos": 6,
          "endPos": 6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "whats the status of s5",
      "intent": "StatusUpdate",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Ticket",
          "startPos": 4,
          "endPos": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "whats the status of s9",
      "intent": "StatusUpdate",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Ticket",
          "startPos": 4,
          "endPos": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "please tell me the status of s24",
      "intent": "StatusUpdate",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Ticket",
          "startPos": 6,
          "endPos": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I added one more utterance taking it to 7, and now it is picking up Ticket.    I had been thrown off because it was managing with only 3 or so utterances with other intents and entities I'd trained it with.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please mark the question as answered :)